# Restrict user to input numbers

Tags: java

```
`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter your name:");
 String userName = scanner.nextLine();
 if (scanner.hasNextDouble()){
 System.out.println("You can't enter numbers");
  }`
```

> Here i can't print "You can't enter numbers". Or is there any other option to restrict user to input numbers?

Comment: you can add check whether it is a number to not using `regex` inside a `while` loop.

Comment: You cant restrict what the user can enter. They can enter anything they want. All you can do is to loop until the user entered what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out something like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean validUsername = false;
    String regexForNumbers = ".*\\d.*";

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
    while (!validUsername) {
        String userName = scanner.nextLine();
        if(userName.matches(regexForNumbers)){
            System.out.println("Username Can not contain numbers");
            System.out.println("Please Enter username again:");
        }else{
            validUsername = true;
        }
    }
 }
```

Here `String regexForNumbers = ".*\\d.*";` will check whether the username contains a number,and you can expect something like this,

```
Enter your name:
maneesha123
Username Can not contain numbers

Please Enter username again:
123
Username Can not contain numbers

Please Enter username again:
maneesha
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, use the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex) to make sure numerical digits have not been supplied. The `"\\D"` regex does exactly that, for example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String userName = "";
while (userName.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter your User name: --> ");
    userName = scanner.nextLine();
    // Anything is acceptable 'except' numerical digits.
    if (!userName.matches("\\D+")) { 
        System.err.println("Invalid name supplied (" + userName + ")!.\n"
                    + "Numerical digits are not permitted! Try again...");
        userName = ""; 
    }
}
System.out.println("Acceptable: " + userName);
```